# How to break out of .then in Cypress when requirement is met

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to click on the element until I get the text value I need. The problem is, after satisfying the if statement, forEach loop continues to run and I can't find a way to break it. Here is my code, any help is welcome, thanks!

```
export function setCalendarDate(i, month, date){
    let genArr = Array.from({length:12})
    cy.wrap(genArr).each((index) => {
        cy.get(LocatorsContact.calendarMonthTitle).eq(i).then(($btn) => {
            const txt = $btn.text();
            if (txt === month) {
                cy.get(date).click({force: true});
            }
            else {
                cy.get(LocatorsContact.calendarForwardButton).click();
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `.each()` loop is synchronous but the exit condition is depeneding on asynchronous code

```js
cy.get(LocatorsContact.calendarMonthTitle).then($btn= >  // result is asynchronous
```

The `.each()` does have an early exit strategy, you can `return false` inside the loop to stop it, but it requires a ***synchronous*** return.

The other problem is parameter `i` is passed in, but it never changes, so the loop does the same thing each time. You probably want to use `index` instead to get different button on each iteration.

---

Instead of looping, I would use a recursive function:

```js
const setCalendarDate = (month, date, attempts = 0) => { 

  if (attempts === 100) throw 'Too many attempts'

  cy.get('div')
    .then($els => Cypress._.map($els, el => el.innerText))   // all texts as array
    .then(texts => {
      if (texts.includes(month)) {
        cy.get(date).click()
      } else {
        cy.get(LocatorsContact.calendarForwardButton).click()
        cy.then(() => setCalendarDate(month, date, ++attempts))  // next 
      }
    })
}

// initial call
setCalendarDate(month, date)
```

Everything controlling the recursion is ***inside*** the callback, so it doesn't matter that the code is asynchronous.